# Programming against interfaces in Java

Tags: java, interfaces, static-methods

Supposing I have an interface Foo and a given implementation FooImpl.

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo
```

If I want to define a new operation on this class that depends on the particular implementation, is it correct to define it in the implementation class or as a static method on an Util class like FooUtils.operation?

```
public class FooImpl {
  public void operation() {
    ...
  }
}

public class FooUtils {
  public static void operation(Foo f) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The first option forces me to cast to the given implementation class whenever I want to use it on an object that is declared of the type of the interface (it is good practice to program against interfaces). For example:

```
Foo f = FooImpl.newInstance();
((FooImpl) f).operation();
```

which is a bit ugly.

The second option doesn't have this problem but it is not very pretty either:

```
FooUtils.operation(f)
```

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Design for an interface implementation that provides additional functionality](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/242993/design-for-an-interface-implementation-that-provides-additional-functionality)

Comment: In a nuttshell, variable f should be declared as FooImpl if you need to call operation(). You can pass f to methods which operate on Foo, but methods that operate on Foo shouldn't cast a Foo to anything, so shouldn't call operation().

Answer (score 9):

If not every implementer of `Foo` is supposed to contain `operation()`, then `operation()` cannot be declared in `Foo`, plain and simple.

Programming against interfaces rather than concrete classes is a good idea, but only if the interface actually is sufficient for your needs. If you need to call `operation()`, then you should declare `FooImpl`, or maybe a custom subinterface of `Foo`, but never `Foo`. That would completely subvert the point of using an interface: not having to know concrete subclasses.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can define methods on the interface and as long as you implement them there you don't have to implement them at every implementor (at least in Java 8).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum In fact, Java only supports that from Java 8 onwards and it has some limitations. For example, you are very limited in what the `default` implementation can access.

Answer (score 0):

- First, if you find yourself always doing casting before calling some operation, it might be a sign that there's something wrong with your inheritance structure. If your inheritance is good, all the methods can be called by other classes are exposed in the interface and you will not need to do casting
- Not everything needs to be abstracted in the interface. You will generally use interface for testability (to introduce fake object easily) or if you have several implementation. I'll not use interface for domain entities.
- Whether to put operation in the class or in another class, need to see the nature of the operation. Does the operation use most of the fields from this class? If so most probably it belongs to this class. For me, generally I'll try to avoid static method, unless it's really something not related to domain logic